# Dirac's paper on classically radiating electrons: scalar product of $ev_{\gamma}f^{\nu}_{\mu}$ with $v$ is zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, classical-electrodynamics

In Dirac's paper, [classical Theory of Radiating Electrons](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/167/929/148), he analyzes electromagnetic radiation entering and leaving a world tube surrounding the world line of a charge moving under the influence of this electromagnetic radiation, and shows that
$$\frac{1}{2}e^2\epsilon^{-1}\dot{v_{\mu}}-ev_{\gamma}f^{\nu}_{\mu}=\dot{B_\mu}\tag{18}$$
$e$ charge
$\epsilon$ small real number representing the width of a tube surrounding the world line of the charge
$v$ four velocity of the charge
$f$ a function of the actual, retarded and advanced electromagnetic field tensors
$B$ a four vector

He then takes the scalar product of both sides with $v$ to get, using his notation () for the scalar product of two four-vectors:
$$(v\dot{B})= \frac{1}{2}e^2\epsilon^{-1}(\dot{v}v) = 0$$

For this to be true, the scalar product of $v$ with the other term $ev_{\gamma}f^{\nu}_{\mu}$ must equal zero: how does one show this?

**note:** It's really bizarre that Dirac feels the need to state the far more obvious identities $(v\dot v)=0$, $v^2 = 1$ just before this bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $F^{\mu\nu}$ is skew-symmetric. Thus
$$
v^\mu v^\nu F_{\mu\nu}\equiv 0
$$

One should point out that, in Dirac's article,
$$
f_{\mu\nu}=F_{\mu\nu}+\frac43e\ddot v_{[\mu}v_{\nu]}
$$
which is still skew in $\mu,\nu$, and therefore $v^\mu v^\nu f_{\mu\nu}$ also vanishes.

Comment: It's really bizarre that Dirac feels the need to state the far more obvious identity $(v\dot v)=0$ in equation (16) !